# Download zip file using URL in java

Tags: java, rest, httpclient

I have the below code to download a file using the httpclient from a URL. Though the program works it only downloads 3k everytime I run it. 
I have setup a few proxies to overcome the corporate network and am trying the below code to automate the downloads from an external website.

The site has a few other files(like video, audio as well). Even when I try with them the size is 3k. I am using their REST interface to get the files. Is there something I need to change in my code to make it work still ?

```
url = "https://samforloogin.com/video.zip";

URI uri = URI.create(url);

DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                .build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri); 
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet); 
java.io.InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent(); 

String filePath = "C:\\Users\\smandodd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\8ee47df6c5a44c9d9c8ff3326d932819\\screenshots.flv";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath )); 
int inByte; 
while((inByte = is.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println("The number of bytes read are" + inByte);
    fos.write(inByte); 
}
is.close(); 
fos.close();
```

Comment: What text do you see in `screenshots.flv`? It will probably be some text indicating the HTTP error.

Comment: What do you see when you run this in the debugger?  You _have_ run it in the debugger, haven't you?

Comment: @MartinKonecny thank you the file does have the error message...

Comment: It works fine now with the below update

`CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
   credsProvider.setCredentials(
                 new AuthScope("proxy-aep.com", 8080),
                 new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myself", "mypassword"));
  
   DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
   CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                       .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                       .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                       .build();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to download files in general:

```
URL website = new URL("https://samforloogin.com/video.zip");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```